# How do I make discord bot able to set text message for specific member?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

My english is not good, I'm a native speaker, but I hope I can explain what I want.
I'm trying to make my bot able to set specific text for each member, example if I type !setmsg Hello world! the bot will set message to Hello world!, if I type !message it will send Hello world!

But the problem is Everyone that type !message also get Hello world! I do not want that!
Please help, thanks!

```
m = ""
@x.command()
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def setmsg(ctx, msg:str):
    global m
    m = msg
    await ctx.send('set message to '+m)

@x.command()
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def message(ctx):
    global m
    await ctx.send(m)
```

Everyone that type !message also get Hello world!
I do not want that, I want people to be able to set their own message and the bot will send what they set their message as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary that maps ids to messages:

```
messages = {}

@x.command()
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def setmsg(ctx, *, msg:str):
    messages[ctx.author.id] = msg
    await ctx.send('set message to ' + msg)

@x.command()
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def message(ctx):
    await ctx.send(messages.get(ctx.author.id, "Default Message"))
```